# Apache Commons Imaging - convert tiff to jpg

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-imaging

I need to convert a `tiff` image into a `jpg` one using Apache Commons Imaging.
I tried to but I can't figure out how to do it using this library.

```
final BufferedImage image = Imaging.getBufferedImage(new File(image));
final ImageFormat format = ImageFormats.JPEG;
final Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
return Imaging.writeImageToBytes(image, format, params);
```

Where `image` is my `tiff` file to be converted, but I get

> org.apache.commons.imaging.ImageWriteException: This image format (Jpeg-Custom) cannot be written.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong could someone help?

Comment: My guess is that this conversion may not be possible (not supported) using Apache Commons Imaging. Are you open to other alternatives? What are your project constraints?

Comment: I just need a library that does the conversion and works on open-jdk (I'm on 8 right now)
I'm trying to figure out if Apache Commons Imaging can do that, but apparently it doesn't.
So whatever works is ok (except for JAI)

Comment: Apache Commons Imaging has [no write support for JPEG](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/formatsupport.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the use of java AWT:

```
   import java.awt.Color;
   import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
```

And code:

```
  // TIFF image file read
  BufferedImage tiffImage = ImageIO.read(new File("tiff-image.tiff"));
  // Prepare the image before writing - with same dimensions
  BufferedImage jpegImage = new BufferedImage(
          tiffImage.getWidth(),
          tiffImage.getHeight(), 
          BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
  // Draw image from original TIFF to the new JPEG image
  jpegImage.createGraphics().drawImage(tiffImage, 0, 0, Color.WHITE, null);
  // Write the image as JPEG to disk
  ImageIO.write(jpegImage, "jpg", new File("jpeg-image.jpg"));
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! However I had to install this plugin to read the tiff image with ImageIO: https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys